# How to access `setup`'s inner state without exposing it via `data`?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, tsx

This question is specific to `setup` returning render function.

For instance, I have a component `Foo`:

```
// Foo.tsx
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    //  how to access `number` outside the `Foo` Component?
    const number = ref(0)

    return () => <div>{number.value}</div>
  },
})
```

Do we have to use `data` to expose `number`? For example:

```
// Foo.tsx
import { defineComponent, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      //  expose `number` to the outside
      number: 0,
    }
  },
  setup() {
    return () => <div>{getCurrentInstance()?.data.number}</div>
  },
})

// FooContainer.tsx
import Foo from '@/views/Foo'
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const foo = ref<InstanceType<typeof Foo>>()
    //                           use `Foo`'s `number` in `FooContainer`
    onMounted(() => console.log(foo.value?.number))

    return () => <Foo ref={foo} />
  },
})
```

So, is there any other way to access `Foo`'s `setup`'s inner state `number` without exposing it via `data`?

Comment: The problem is specific to the use of render function, isn't it? The question doesn't explicitly explain this. Otherwise there seems to be no issue, the instance is just returned from setup.

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry, I missed it. Yes, it's specific to render function usage. In this case, without declaring `number` in `data`, can the outside access `Foo`'s `setup`'s inner state `number`?

Comment: what's your real use case?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim For example, making a util function that toggles a `VTable`'s `loading` state, but if `loading` is not exposed from `data`, I found it impossible to control it from outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expose your data to other components using `expose` method provided in setup,

```
// Foo.tsx
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, { expose }) {
    //  how to access `number` outside the `Foo` Component?
    const number = ref(0)

    expose({
        number
    })

    return () => <div>{number.value}</div>
  },
})
```

Comment: How did you find this, it's not even documented :O.

Comment: I was facing with the same problem lol. So I just played around. Checked what setup provided and eventually found `expose`. But yeah no idea why it's not documented.

Comment: Corresponding RFC: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/210

Answer (score 1):

You could define a composable function called `useLoader`:

useLoader.ts:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

const loading = ref(false)

export default function useLoader() {
  return {
    loading,
  }
}
```

then use it in `Foo.tsx` like:

```
import { defineComponent, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
import useLoader from './userLoader'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { loading } = useLoader()

    return () => <div>{loading.value && <div> Loading ... </div>}</div>
  },
})
```

FooContainer.tsx

```
import Foo from '@/views/Foo'
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import useLoader from './userLoader'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { loading } = useLoader()

    onMounted(() => console.log(loading.value))

    return () => <Foo />
  },
})
```